# Unsupported operand types when adding two values

Tags: php, session

I cleared the `$_SESSION` using `session_unset()`

now my program isn't working. Please help

```
if (isset($_POST['Add_To_Cart'])) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cartridge_scale'])){
        $_SESSION['cartridge_scale'] = array();
    }

    if(($_SESSION['cartridge_scale']+findItemHeight()) <= 3){
        more code etc etc
        {
```

Now I get a

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types

this error happens on the line

```
if(($_SESSION['cartridge_scale']+findItemHeight()) <= 3)
```

Again, I recently used `session_unset()` to clear the `$_SESSION` but I don't think that would cause the program to crash.

Comment: Why did you only post half of the error message? You can't add an array and a number.

Answer (score 1):

Change the array to integer

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cartridge_scale'])){
    $_SESSION['cartridge_scale'] = 0;
}
```

because you cannot add a **number** with array

```
if(($_SESSION['cartridge_scale']+findItemHeight()) <= 3)
```